# Two different web bundles in karaf is causing issues

Tags: rest, jersey, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I have implemented two rest based operations. Each operation resides inside two different web bundles(projects). When i deploy the first web bundle. I was able to access the rest based operations which are exposed. After deploying the second i am not able to access the first web bundle's rest apis, but second bundles rest apis are accessible.

web.xml first bundle

```
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.dummy.services</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

web.xml second bundle

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.trial.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/http</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

First Bundle Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1457440522534
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_79
Built-By: 609620968
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: customBasedWebService Jersey Webapp
Bundle-SymbolicName: customBasedWebService
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Import-Package: javax.ws.rs;version="[1.1,2)",javax.ws.rs.core;version="
[1.1,2)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.6,2)",org.osgi.framework.wiring;versio n="[1.0,2)",com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet;version="[1.19,2)",com .sun.jersey.api.core;version="[1.19,2)"
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
Web-ContextPath: trial
Webapp-Context: trial
```

Second Bundle Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1457439145540
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_79
Built-By: 609620968
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ORGAdminServices Jersey Webapp65
Bundle-SymbolicName: ORGAdminServices
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Import-Package: javax.ws.rs;version="[1.1,2)",javax.ws.rs.core;version=" [1.1,2)",javax.servlet;version="[3.1,4)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.6,2)",com.sun.jersey.api.core;version="[1.19,2)",com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet;version="[1.19,2)"
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
Web-ContextPath: ORGadmin
Webapp-Context: ORGadmin
```

Do i need to add something to make it work?

```
JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()
2016-03-09 10:32:50,905 | INFO  | nsole user karaf | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Adding features: ORGAdminServices/[0.0.1.SNAPSHOT,0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
2016-03-09 10:33:57,134 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Changes to perform:
2016-03-09 10:33:57,134 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   Region: root
2016-03-09 10:33:57,134 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |     Bundles to install:
2016-03-09 10:33:57,134 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:ORGAdminServices/ORGAdminServices/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,134 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:com.github.romix/java-concurrent-hash-trie-map/0.2.23
2016-03-09 10:33:57,134 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.5.1
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.CR2
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/concepts/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/object-cache-api/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/util/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-common/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-model-api/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-model-util/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-parser-api/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-parser-impl/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final/jar/tests
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.1.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.0.1.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,138 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA
2016-03-09 10:33:57,142 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,142 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |       wrap:mvn:org.reflections/reflections/0.9.9-RC1
2016-03-09 10:33:57,142 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Installing bundles:
2016-03-09 10:33:57,142 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:ORGAdminServices/ORGAdminServices/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,154 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:com.github.romix/java-concurrent-hash-trie-map/0.2.23
2016-03-09 10:33:57,166 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.5.1
2016-03-09 10:33:57,178 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1
2016-03-09 10:33:57,202 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,234 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.CR2
2016-03-09 10:33:57,242 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/concepts/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,254 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/object-cache-api/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,262 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/util/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,274 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-common/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,286 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-model-api/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,298 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-model-util/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,310 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-parser-api/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,318 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/yang-parser-impl/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,334 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:57,342 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final/jar/tests
2016-03-09 10:33:57,350 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,358 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.1.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,386 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.0.1.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,398 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA
2016-03-09 10:33:57,410 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:57,414 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap:mvn:org.reflections/reflections/0.9.9-RC1
2016-03-09 10:33:57,426 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Stopping bundles:
2016-03-09 10:33:57,426 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   customBasedWebService/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:57,426 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | Activator                        | 141 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 4.2.3 | Destroying extension for bundle customBasedWebService
2016-03-09 10:33:57,434 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | PackagesResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.company.services
2016-03-09 10:33:57,682 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Root resource classes found:
  class org.company.services.YangBasedServices
2016-03-09 10:33:57,682 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | No provider classes found.
2016-03-09 10:33:57,686 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | WebApplicationImpl               | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
2016-03-09 10:33:57,967 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | PackagesResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.company.services
2016-03-09 10:33:57,995 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Root resource classes found:
  class org.company.services.YangBasedServices
2016-03-09 10:33:57,995 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | No provider classes found.
2016-03-09 10:33:57,995 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | WebApplicationImpl               | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
2016-03-09 10:33:58,167 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | HttpServiceFactoryImpl           | 100 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 4.2.3 | Unbinding bundle: [customBasedWebService [315]]
2016-03-09 10:33:58,167 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   packet.handler/0.0.1
2016-03-09 10:33:58,171 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | BlueprintExtender                | 13 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.5 | Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle packet.handler/0.0.1
2016-03-09 10:33:58,171 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Refreshing bundles:
2016-03-09 10:33:58,171 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |     customBasedWebService/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT (Wired to packet.handler/0.0.1 which is being refreshed)
2016-03-09 10:33:58,171 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |     packet.handler/0.0.1 (Should be wired to: ORGAdminServices/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT (through [packet.handler/0.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=nextgen.hibernate.auto.generate)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=1.0.0)))"))
2016-03-09 10:33:58,183 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Starting bundles:
2016-03-09 10:33:58,183 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.apache.commons.collections/3.2.1
2016-03-09 10:33:58,187 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305_3.0.0_jsr305-3.0.0.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,187 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.concepts/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,191 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_javassist_javassist_3.16.1-GA_javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,191 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_reflections_reflections_0.9.9-RC1_reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,191 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.object-cache-api/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,195 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_jboss_spec_javax_transaction_jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec_1.0.0.Final_jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,195 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging/3.1.0.CR2
2016-03-09 10:33:58,199 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_hibernate_common_hibernate-commons-annotations_4.0.1.Final_hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,199 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_hibernate_hibernate-core_4.0.1.Final_hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,203 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_hibernate_hibernate-entitymanager_4.0.1.Final_hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,203 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.antlr.antlr4-runtime-osgi/4.5.1
2016-03-09 10:33:58,207 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-common/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,215 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-model-api/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,215 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   com.github.romix.java-concurrent-hash-trie-map/0.2.23
2016-03-09 10:33:58,219 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.util/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,219 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-parser-api/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,223 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-model-util/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,223 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-parser-impl/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,231 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   ORGAdminServices/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,315 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | HttpServiceFactoryImpl           | 100 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 4.2.3 | Binding bundle: [ORGAdminServices [335]] to http service
2016-03-09 10:33:58,319 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   org.hibernate.validator/4.2.0.Final
2016-03-09 10:33:58,327 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | will add org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer to ServletContainerInitializers
2016-03-09 10:33:58,327 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | Skipt org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer, because specialized handler will be present
2016-03-09 10:33:58,327 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | will add com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer to ServletContainerInitializers
2016-03-09 10:33:58,327 | WARN  | pool-85-thread-1 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | failed to parse and instantiate of javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer in classpath
2016-03-09 10:33:58,331 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | will add org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer to ServletContainerInitializers
2016-03-09 10:33:58,375 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   packet.handler/0.0.1
2016-03-09 10:33:58,383 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   customBasedWebService/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
2016-03-09 10:33:58,563 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | HttpServiceFactoryImpl           | 100 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 4.2.3 | Unbinding bundle
2016-03-09 10:33:58,567 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 |   wrap_file__C__Users_609620968_.m2_repository_org_hibernate_common_hibernate-commons-annotations_4.0.1.Final_hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final-tests.jar/0.0.0
2016-03-09 10:33:58,567 | INFO  | ool-115-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Done.
2016-03-09 10:33:58,951 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | added ServletContainerInitializer: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer
2016-03-09 10:33:58,959 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | HttpServiceContext               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | registering context WebAppHttpContext{ORGAdminServices - 335}, with context-name: trial
2016-03-09 10:33:58,963 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | will add org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer to ServletContainerInitializers
2016-03-09 10:33:58,967 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | Skipt org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer, because specialized handler will be present
2016-03-09 10:33:58,967 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | will add com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer to ServletContainerInitializers
2016-03-09 10:33:58,967 | WARN  | pool-85-thread-2 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | failed to parse and instantiate of javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer in classpath
2016-03-09 10:33:58,967 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | will add org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer to ServletContainerInitializers
2016-03-09 10:33:59,051 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | JettyServerWrapper               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | added ServletContainerInitializer: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer
2016-03-09 10:33:59,071 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | HttpServiceContext               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | registering context WebAppHttpContext{customBasedWebService - 315}, with context-name: ORGadmin
2016-03-09 10:33:59,075 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | HttpServiceContext               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | registering JasperInitializer
2016-03-09 10:33:59,075 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | HttpServiceContext               | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 4.2.3 | registering JasperInitializer
2016-03-09 10:33:59,195 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | PackagesResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.company.services
2016-03-09 10:33:59,199 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | PackagesResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.company.services
2016-03-09 10:33:59,235 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Root resource classes found:
  class org.company.services.YangBasedServices
2016-03-09 10:33:59,235 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | No provider classes found.
2016-03-09 10:33:59,239 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Root resource classes found:
  class org.company.services.YangBasedServices
2016-03-09 10:33:59,239 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | ScanningResourceConfig           | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | No provider classes found.
2016-03-09 10:33:59,239 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | WebApplicationImpl               | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
2016-03-09 10:33:59,243 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | WebApplicationImpl               | 319 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.19.0 | Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
2016-03-09 10:33:59,593 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-1 | ContextHandler                   | 80 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{ORGAdminServices - 335}}
2016-03-09 10:33:59,599 | INFO  | pool-85-thread-2 | ContextHandler                   | 80 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.10.v20150310 | Started HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{customBasedWebService - 315}}
```

Comment: Are the two bundle's name the same ?, Can you post the MANIFEST.MF contents for each of bundle ?

Comment: I have updated the question with MANIFEST.MF contents.

Comment: do you register services or filters programmatically in your bundle? I don't think the issue is in your web.xml

Comment: How do you deploy the bundles ? Can you post the karaf.log ?

Comment: Alex i have updated the post with the log from the point i install the second web bundle.

Comment: @jermie i am not installing any bundles programatically. FYI feature.xml of  both the bundles have jersey dependencies marked for installation is it because of that this is happening. But if i do a web:list i am able to see both the bundles as active and deployed.

Comment: I just wished  people with such questions would ask at the mailinglists instead of here, as a forum like question and answer approach is much more feasable as this issue isn't a "question -> answer" thing. Right now my gutt feeling is telling me, the "shared" jersey bundle is screwing it up. The web.xml and Manifest looks good, so the only thing that might be of influence is the jersey one. If you deploy each wab bundle "standalone" the application is running I guess? So maybe Jersey is mixing the second into the first call. You need to check if it's possible to have some sort of factory.

Comment: @Achim you are right if i deploy each wab bundle standalone the application works.This will stop working when more than one wab bundle is deployed.  Will try to create a factory if there are no other options.

Comment: Again, on a mailinglist this would have been easier. But maybe you need a service aproach. Right now you're doing the import Packages, maybe the jersey bundle is also doing some imports. As you're trying to create Rest Services, why not go with CXF it is known to work nicely in an OSGi environment.